# I have latest Ubuntu and my realtec wireless network in my laptop stop working '

Tags: networking

I have a Realtec RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter and according to it, it shows I'm connected but when I start to open up Firfox it just sits there and spins... I have tried everything I can to see about maybe it was the pc but its not. What do I do now?

Comment: I did as you suggested and found that my network is working just fine but I can not delete nor change Firefox! It's locked on the root directory and I do not have permission to delete it! How can I install a different browser like opera or chrome on this machine and bypass Mozilla?

Answer (score 1):

Occasionally, the local firefox profile may become corrupt or unusable if firefox was shutdown incorrectly or crashed.

First, let's verify the issue is only with firefox. Open a Terminal Window, and type:

```
nslookup google.com
```

if results are returned, your wireless device is connected to the network and functioning as it should. Otherwise, issue the command: `ifconfig -a` to view a list of all adapters and their associated configurations.

If you do not see the device listed there, try `wifi-status`.

If you see your device in at least one of those lists, with an IP Address: 192.168.xxx.xxx - the ip address shown will depend on the subnet configured.
You are connected, or there may a be DNS related issue.

If results were returned for nslookup, then try the following:
Navigate back to your home folder(each line hit enter)

```
cd 
rm -R ./.mozilla
```

Comment: I did as you suggested and the network card is working and its sending data along with receiving data. I tried to delete Mozilla and it will not allow me to do so because its in root directory and I do not have permission to access the root. What can I do to get this to surf again?

Comment: the 'cd ' command by itself, should deposit you into your home directory. to verify, issue this command 'pwd' should display something like /home/username. if still an issue, try 'sudo rm -R ./.mozilla'.